# Invoke Threads using JMX

Tags: java, multithreading, jmx

How can I use JMX to invoke a thread using jConsole or jManage ?

I want to initially create 5 threads. Let them run. Then when one of them gets stuck, I want to create a new thread to continue operations.

I do not want to kill process until complete data is not processed / until really required.

Answer (score 0):

You question seems a little bit vague; in general thread always runs some logic, so you should do some development here.

Basically JMX provides a way to install component (called MBean) and run it along with JVM process.

Java allows to start a JMX server along with the JVM process, in order to do that you should supply some properties to the process.
Then you can use this server for installing your own MBean that can do whatever you want, and of course run the thread.

Once you have a deployed mbean component and your jvm proces is up and running you can use jConsole and you should see your mbean among others.
Then just call the method.

There is a really good tutorial [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jmx/index.html)

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for reply. I will get back with some sample code to explain my question in little bit detail.